# How can I know when a google font have been loaded completely in flutter for web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm currently writing a webpage with flutter. In that, I'm using GoogleFonts package and I would like to know when the font has been loaded completely if there's a way to do that.
The reason why I want to know that is below.

I'm wrapping the google fonts text with the AutoSizeText package(https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) and it does not work properly when the first time you open the page because the AutoSizeText optimizes the font size for the default font, not the google font, since the google font has not been loaded yet. Consequently, the google font sometimes overflows the bounds. My workaround for it is to force reload the widget after a few seconds by doing something like this but it does not feel right.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    waitForSomeMoment();
  }

  void waitForSomeMoment() async {
    await Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      () {
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to know that. But instead, you can bundle font files in your assets. Check out the end of the [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) page to learn how.

Comment: Yeah I am actually doing it, but still there's a slight lag to load the font even if it's in my assets. Maybe it's a web specific thing (I'm not sure because I currently don't have an app development environment).

Comment: Well, while I agree it's not optimal, a single rebuild is not dramatic either. You can always open an issue to ask for a callback feature on the [github repo](https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/issues).

Comment: I wanted to check if there's a way without changing a source code beforehand. I'll open an issue. Thank you for the link.

Comment: No problem ! :)

Comment: I'm also experiencing this little lag on mobile. Have you created an issue yet? And how did you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So I actually slacked off in creating the issue. But seems like someone is currently implementing this here (https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/pull/195).

Answer (score 0):

From the [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) package docs

> Visual font swapping. To avoid visual font swaps that occur when a
> font is loading, use `FutureBuilder` and `GoogleFonts.pendingFonts()`.

Here's an [example app](https://github.com/material-foundation/flutter-packages/blob/main/packages/google_fonts/example/lib/example_font_selection.dart)